# WPF/Silverlight Tree - How do I make all nodes from a tree to be aligned?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, tree, nodes, alignment

What do I have to do with a Tree in WPF/Silverlight, to have all nodes aligned ar the same level? 
 I mean I need the root and all childs to be align at the same distance from the left side of the screen. Is that possible? 
 Actually I am using a Telerik Silverlight RadTreeView.

Any help is welcomed,
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Telerik control in particular, but what you'll probably need to do is provide a custom ControlTemplate.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx) includes information on customizing the standard WPF TreeView, which may help get you started.